# Session variables resets on the refresh of the page

Tags: php, ajax, session-variables

I`m trying to create a mock login for a website but whenever I try to save the username in a session, when the page reloads, it resets the session to 1. I put on session.auto_start on thinking it was a session_start issue but it's still happening

my header.php

```
    <?php
        if($_SESSION['user'] != 1){
            $user = $_SESSION['user'];
    ?>
        <input type='submit' id='accEdit' value='Edit Account'/>
        <label class='clickLog'>Welcome: <?=$user?></label>
    <?php
        }else{
    ?>
    <input type='hidden' id='accEdit' value='Edit Account'/>
    <p id="clickLog">Login?</p>
    <?php
        }

    ?>
```

the function

```
 case "login":

        $user = $_POST['user'];
        $pass = $_POST['pass']; 
        if($user = "Cody" && $pass = "1234"){
            $_SESSION['user'] = $user;
            echo "yes";
        }else{
            echo "no";
        }
        exit;
```

the ajax call

```
function login(user,pass){
    var action = "login";
    $.ajax({
        url:'appedit.php',
        type: "POST",
        data: {action:action,user:user,pass:pass},
        success: function(response){
            if(response == "yes"){
                alert(response);
                $("#clickLog").html("<label class='clickLog'>Welcome: " + $user + "</label>");
                $("#clickLog").show();
                $("#accEdit").prop("type", "submit");
            }else{
                alert(response + "fail");
                $("#clickLog").show();
            }
        },              
        error: function (request, status, error) {
            alert(error);
        }
    });
}
```

I know that it's not the best looking code but I'm just trying to patch something together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're assigning here

```
if($user = "Cody" && $pass = "1234"){
         ^                 ^
```

where you should be comparing

```
if($user == "Cody" && $pass == "1234"){
         ^^                 ^^
```

using 2x equal signs.

- 1 equal sign => assign
- 2 equal signs => compare
- 3 equal signs => if identical

Consult the manual http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Plus, do make sure that the session was indeed started `session_start();` inside all pages using sessions.

- Use `isset()`.
- Use `!empty()`.

---

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Error reporting should only be done in staging, and never production.

- Check your console.

**Additionally** If you're planning to move forward with creating a login system [don't limit passwords](http://jayblanchard.net/security_fail_passwords.html)  and [use the proper methods to hash and verify passwords with PHP](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html).

If you plan to continue using the [AJAX function provided by jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) you should be aware that certain return functions have been deprecated and will be removed soon:

> Deprecation Notice: The jqXHR.success(), jqXHR.error(), and jqXHR.complete() callbacks are deprecated as of jQuery 1.8. To prepare your code for their eventual removal, use jqXHR.done(), jqXHR.fail(), and jqXHR.always() instead.

Comment: thank you, I spent more time then a care to admit on that